# Need help reading a schematic, is this a 220k log b pot?

Tags: potentiometer, vacuum-tube, guitar-amplifier

This is saying a 220k log b potentiometer for the tone pot VR8, correct? That is such an extremely odd value, but I don't see that sort of notation very often either and I wanted to make sure I'm not misinterpreting. Thanks!

[image: Laney Lionheart L5T-112]

Comment: B is a linear pot. A is log.

Comment: Can you add your comment as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a reference, unfortunately. Without it the answer won't be credible. If I have one, I will add.

Comment: Now I have it. Check it out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. also on the wiki [page for pots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) under heading "Resistance–position relationship"

Comment: I think 220K is a rare value for a pot - 200K or 250K should be suitable substitutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the table given on [this page](http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer/), `"A"` stands for *logarithmic* potentiometer (*A*udio), and `B` is standing for linear one (In Asia and America at least):

[image]

Comment: Got to love the discrepancies from country to country. >_<

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yeah... well, at least the `B` thing is unique.

Comment: The taper goes by manufacturer, not country. Yes there are a typical schemes, but the manufacturer sets that label.

Comment: I hate it when someone edits my posts, and gets it wrong... and I get negative marks because of it....